# Why the 7 laws for Bnei Noach do not include Shabbat or the separation between clean/unclean animals

Tags: shabbat, kashrut-kosher, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, noachide-laws

I would like to ask why the Bnei Noah are not required to keep shabbat whereas the Shabbat has been holy since the first week of creation and has been given to humanity not only to AM Ysrael? 
In fact even in Mt Sinai : Hashem said "Zachor et Yom Hashabbat" (Remember the day of Shabbat) which means that it was not something new. 
And the second question is that the TORAH clearly stated that Noah knew the difference between clean and unclean animals. So why the Bnei Noah are not required to "eat" only the clean animals? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Rav Hirsch explains that the animals were shown to be the ones that Noachides were going to be offering on the altar to Hashem. I would consider this to be based on the Bnai Yisrael becoming a ממלכת כוהנים. Thus, the restrictions on Bnai Yisrael as compared to the rest of the world are analogous to the restrictions on the kohanim with respect to the rest of Bnai Yisrael. This analogy would also apply to the Shabbat. Kedushah (holiness) is the separation and restriction required of the kohanim. Just as the kohanim are separated from the remainder of Bnai Yisrael, so too are the Bnai Yisrael separated from the rest of mankind.

The point is that the animals with respect to Bnai Noach are such that the animals, when they were offered on the altar, could not be eaten. The Bnai Noach were allowed to eat any animal that had not been brought on the altar. Only certain animals were allowed on the altar, though they could be eaten if they had not been brought. Bnai Yisrael on receiving the Torah at Sinai, were raised in kedushah (holiness), so that they were only allowed to eat animals that were permitted to be brought on the altar. Animals that were actually brought on the altar were restricted even further.

Animals that Bnai Yisrael bring on the altar are restricted even more than other animals so that certain offerings may be eaten only by kohanim, and certain others only under specific circumstances by those who brought them (Korbon Pesach and other Shelamim as examples).

Note that Hashem did restrict the eating of flesh to an extent so as to show that it is only by the permission of Hashem [Noach 9:3-4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8173#v=3&showrashi=true). Rav Hirsch explains this as well.

Rav Hirsch explains in [Noach 7:2}(http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8170#v=2&showrashi=true)

> Of all the clean animals you shall take for yourself seven pairs, a
>   male and its mate, and of the animals that are not clean, two, a male
>   and its mate.
>
> Although at that time animal flesh was not an object of human
>   consumption and the difference between "pure" and "impure" animals was
>   only made later by the laws given on Sinai, nevertheless already here
>   Hashem designates animals to Noah by the characteristic of being
>   "pure". So that there must, already then, have been some occasion for
>   making this distinction, and this occasion was offerings, for
>   Noachides also were not allowed  - and are not allowed - to bring
>   other than pure animals as sacrifieces. (Zevachim 115a). So that it is
>   only that which is fit for *all* men to offer, that Jews are allowed
>   to eat. The Jewish table and the Noachian altar stand at the same
>   level. The choice of animals for both must accordingly have the same
>   motive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments.
However I really doubt that Noah ate impure animal. In fact in his comments to the Parashat Noach, Rashi already said that Noach followed the TORAH. 
So it is not only an image of Bnei Ysrael becoming mamlekhet cohanym , it is something that even the Bnei Noach should follow. 
I am pretty sure Noach kept the shabbat. and Shabbat was made since the dawn of time. So why the bnei Noach are not required to keep shabbat?

Comment: @EphraimLevy in the case of Noach, Rav Hirsch says he learned the Torah in order to know which animals were tahor but the restrictions to eat only animals suitable for the altar were left to the priesthood. Thus perhaps Noach, Shem (Malkitzedek) did so like Abraham, but it was only the kohanim that would be so restricted.

Comment: Many thanks,
But the animal tahor are also fit for eating, because the Cohanym "eat" them. 
And in the torah not only the cohanym follow the kashrut but every Bnei Israel.

Comment: @EphraimLevy The point is that the animals with respect to Bnai Noach are such that the animals, when they were offered on the altar, could not be eaten. The Bnai Noach were allowed to eat any animal that had not been brought on the altar. Only certain animals were allowed on the altar, though they could be eaten if they had not been brought. Bnai Yisrael on receiving the  Torah at Sinai, were raised in kedushah (holiness), so that they were only allowed to eat animals that were permitted to be brought on the altar. Animals that were actually brought on the altar were restricted even further.

Comment: @sabahillel Thanks a lot for your answer my friend.  
And for the Shabbat? it was given to humanity not only Bnei Ysrael?
And also for marriage: the first mitzvah is to get married and have children because it was a mitzvah given to adam harishon . So why the Bnei Noach are not obliged to do it?

Comment: @EphraimLevy  [Noach 9:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8173#v=7&showrashi=true) Rashi explains it as part of *Do not murder*. Rav Hirsch explains it as part of the general establishment of the new circumstances of the Earth and not an explicit separate command.